# Unit Testing with Realm: Undeclared Type

Tags: swift, unit-testing, realm

```
import RealmSwift

// MARK: Class

/// The DataPoint object representation
public class DataPoint: Object {

  // MARK: - Variables

  /// The latitude of the point
  dynamic var lat: Double = 0
  /// The longitude of the point
  dynamic var lng: Double = 0
  /// The accuracy of the point
  dynamic var accuracy: Double = 0

  /// The added point date of the point
  dynamic var dateAdded: Date = Date()
  /// The last sync date of the point
  dynamic var lastSynced: Date?
}
```

So I have the above simple Realm Object Class. I want to unit test something, irrelevant to Realm at the moment. Originally I have set the target membership of this class to every target (App, UnitTests, UITests) but after I got the duplicate class error I found out that realm requires only the main app target. So I did and I did make the class Public as it was suggested. But now the unit test target does not even build with the error:

```
Undeclared Type 'DataPoint'
```

Any ideas how can I actually solve this error without adding the class to all the target memberships of course.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add App's classes to unit test target. The App target is implicitly linked with unit test target. You can just `@testabe import App` (or `import App` if you use only `public` symbols) in test classes. Make sure selecting "Host Application" and checking "Allow testing Host Application APIs" at "General" tab in unit test target's settings. If none selected "Host Application", Xcode doesn't link App module to unit test target.

On the other hand, you cannot use App module's APIs in UI test. Because during a UI test your test class cannot access your app's code.

From [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html):

> UI testing differs from unit testing in fundamental ways. Unit testing enables you to work within your app's scope and allows you to exercise functions and methods with full access to your app's variables and state. UI testing exercises your app's UI in the same way that users do without access to your app's internal methods, functions, and variables. This enables your tests to see the app the same way a user does, exposing UI problems that users encounter.

If you still in fail it as above, there is something wrong with the setup. Please share the project to reproduce the problem for investigation.